# Async UDP Server with Twisted and QT4

Tags: qt4, udp, twisted

this is the first time I write here. I apologize if my English is not so good.
I want to set up a simple UDP server in Python using Twisted. The GUI is QT4-based and I need to run the application both in Windows or Linux environments.

The code is pretty simple:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class UDPLineReceived(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
    print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)

reactor.listenUDP(int(self.inPort.text()), UDPLineReceived())
reactor.run()
```

It receives the packets sent on the defined port, but it hangs the user interface.
So, I'm wondering how I should change my code in order to get it works in "asynchronous" mode.

If you need other information, please tell me!
Thanks in advance
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PyQt4 integration reactor](https://github.com/ghtdak/qtreactor) to let Twisted and Qt run cooperatively:

```
app = QApplication(...)
import qt4reactor
qt4reactor.install()

from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class UDPLineReceived(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)

reactor.listenUDP(int(self.inPort.text()), UDPLineReceived())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a question: the README file of qt4reactor says to unpack the folder into the PYTHONPATH. But should I unpack it to the Python26 root or in the Lib\SitePackages where is also the twisted folder?